# install CouchDB without a package manager

Tags: redhat, couchdb, start-stop-daemon

I have the ability to shell into a Linux (RHEL6) server, and manage mostly everything, but I don't have root user abilities, so I can't use YUM or any of the available package managers on the box.  Due to some red tape, I've been told if I can get CouchDB installed to just a specific context root, I can then start it up as a service using any server side script.

My problem is, my workstation is a windows machine, and I can't figure out how to get a compiled version of CouchDB installed on the Linux box without using Yum or any other package manager.

Can CouchDB be installed to run as a daemon on just a specific context root, and can I get it uploaded to that root without having to initiate that download from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following (sorry, a lot of steps)

- Get yourself a Linux desktop in a VM, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is free
- Since your server is Redhat, you might be able to skip base Linux install using [a ready image](http://virtualboxes.org/tag/redhat/)
- Install GIT
- Clone the [build-couchdb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb) project and follow the make instructions on the project page
- As a result you have a full self contained couch-db instance in the build directory
- copy the content of the build directory onto your Linux box where you have access
- inside the copied directory structure you will find etc/couchdb/default.ini and local.ini in those files you need to adjust the path to the directory you copied the code
- voila: a ready CouchDB instance

Last step: add the deamon script -> I wonder how that works without root access?

Comment: I've been able to use a cross-compiler to accomplish what I need in terms of building from source on a windows machine and outputting a `.so`, but I still don't know whether or not I can start the couch service as a non-root user.  I do have the ability however, to work with the server admin to permission dirs however we need to, so if couch could be installed inside a context root instead of `/etc/init.d/` I'd probably be good to go.

Comment: on a side note, I've managed to fulfill my needs using [ArangoDB](http://arangodb.org), since it has the compile RHEL version on it's site as MIT licensed software, and I can just upload it directly to any directory I need, and run it from there.  I just need to ensure there aren't any port conflicts on stuff like that.

Comment: Brian,
the build-couchdb compiles couchDB so it can run from the location where it was compiled (or moved to). I run if off my home directory. All the couchDB documentation suggests *NOT* to run it as root, but with a designated user. So you should be good. Feel free to accept the answer :-)